# Speed to break a rock climbing quick draw

Tags: mathematical-physics

I have a quickdraw (a lifesaving device used during rock climbing). It has a strength rating of 22kN (4945.8 pounds force). Assuming I weigh 200 lbs and slow/decelerate over 1 second, how fast would I have to be moving to break the quickdraw?

Comment: This is a physics question, not a math question.

Comment: At your weight of 200#, the quickdraw can take up to $4945.8/200$ g’s of acceleration. 1 g is approximately $32 ft/sec^2$. Multiply this all out and you’ll get something well in excess of 500 mph.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Hence the mathematical-physics tag. Should question be tagged differently, or inappropriate to Mathematics Exchange entirely?

Comment: [Mathematical physics refers to development of mathematical methods for application to problems in physics.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_physics) Not physics problem that happen to involve computations. Yes, this type of question is inappropriate for math.SE. (I suspect they're also inappropriate at physics.SE since they ban homework questions like this.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using impulse of the force and assuming the rope is ideal and your initial velocity is zero, you'd want the resulting force on the rope to be:
$$F_{avg} \lt 22000N = m·a_{avg}=m\frac {\Delta v} {\Delta t} \approx \frac {90.7kg} {1s}·v \Rightarrow v \lt 242.6m/s$$

so a speed greater than approximately $242.6m/s$ will likely  break the quickdraw.